# Array with localStorage doesn't save or gets overwritten?

Tags: javascript, arrays, onclick

In order to summarize the problem I'll explain what the task is first.

So for the eastern event, we are going to add 3 bunny images across a website (different pages, same domain, same website). Once you've found and clicked on all 3 images it should open a new window with a specific URL.

Right now I managed to write the code which saves the clicks of the 3 pictures in an array and then opens the new window with an URL. But sadly it doesn't work once I change the page. The Array either didn't save in the browser storage or gets overwritten once I open a new page.

I'm not exactly sure what the issue is right now. I hope any of you could help me out.

I've tried to work with localStorage and sessionStorage but I don't think I used them properly. I'll provide you with my current code below.

Javascript

```
$(function(){
    var imageStore = [];
    $('.osterhasen').click(function(e){
        localStorage.id = $(this).attr('id');
        // returns index of the element in the array, if the element was not found returns false
        var imageExists = $.inArray(localStorage.id, imageStore);
        if (imageExists >= 0){
            // If element exists, do nothing
            e.preventDefault;
        } else {
            // If element doesn't exist, add element
            imageStore.push(localStorage.id);
        }

        localStorage.setItem('imageStore', JSON.stringify(imageStore));

        localStorageimageStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('imageStore'));

        console.log(localStorageimageStorage);

        if (localStorageimageStorage.length == 3) {
        window.open('https://www.google.ch');
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="1" class="osterhasen"><img src="img/choco.png"></img></div>
      <div id="2" class="osterhasen"><img src="img/geschichte.png"></img></div>
      <div id="3" class="osterhasen"><img src="img/mitarbeiter.jpg"></img></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

In the end the clicks on the images should be saved in the browser storage across the whole website and once you've found all 3 images it should open a new window with a specfic URL.

Thank you very much for your time.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're overriding the key every time. To store an array as you want, you can try the following:

```
  $(function(){
    var imageStore = [];
    $('.osterhasen').click(function(e){

    if(localStorage.getItem('imageStore') === null){ // check if such key exists
        localStorage.setItem('imageStore', JSON.stringify([$(this).attr('id')])); // if it doesn't create an array with first item imageStore and set it to key imagestore
    } else {
        var currentStorage = JSON.parse((localStorage.getItem('imageStore')));
        if(!currentStorage.includes($(this).attr('id')){ // if id doesn't exist add it.
           currentStorage.push($(this).attr('id')); // push to new image inside of it
           localStorage.setItem('imageStore', JSON.stringify(currentStorage)); // set the key to the new value
        }

    }

    localStorageimageStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('imageStore')); // you should have all the 3 pictures here in an array
     console.log(localStorageimageStorage);

        if (localStorageimageStorage.length == 3) {
        window.open('https://www.google.ch');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello

Thank you for your time.

Your version stores the array properly across multiple pages which is good but sadly a new issue occured.

It doesn't check anymore if an image already exists. If I click on the same image 3 times it will add each to the array and then open the URL.
Each image should only be added once and once all 3 are "clicked" it should open a new window.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: @Kryptox can you check this version, I've made some edits

Comment: Hello Vladimir

Thank you so much! It worked perfectly. This is what I was looking for. Thank you!!

Comment: @Kryptox I'm glad it helped, I hope the code is understandable.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign properties to `localStorage` like this (it doesn't exist, and you should be using it's `setItem` method anyway):

```
localstorage.id = $(this).attr('id');
var imageExists = $.inArray(localstorage.id, imageStore);
```

So assign `id` to a variable instead:

```
const id = $(this).attr('id');
const imageExists = $.inArray(id, imageStore);
```

[Working version](https://jsfiddle.net/nx2bwfcz/1/)

Comment: Hello

Thanks for your time. I didn't downvote your comment tho. 

I checked the version and sadly the same issue still persists where after changing the page the Array isn't "stored".

Comment: Where are you changing the page to? You know that localStorage is only available for the document's origin? If you go to your dev tools and open the storage tab in that working demo you can see the data stored in localStorage when you've clicked those elements.

Comment: I'm currently testing this local on my browser.

I made 2 html files to test the "storing" between pages.
example.ch/page.html
example.ch/page2.html

^ is what it looks like. I assume that should work no?

I'm still new to this.